# How to get variables from subshell while also passing arguments with xargs?

Tags: bash

I would like to pass filename to `xargs` and process it in subshell, then get the certain variables from subshell to the current shell. I prefer `xargs` here for parallelizing purposes.

Here is a sample code:

```
files_with_issues=()
printf "%s\n" ${list_of_file_names[@]} | xargs -n1 -P4 -I {file} bash -c '
        # Process the file ...
        exit_status=$?
        [ ${exit_status} -ne 0 ] && files_with_issues+=({file})'

echo "${files_with_issues[@]}"
```

I am considering to use something like `source` or `.` to get variables from subshells. However I could not figure out how to achieve this?

Comment: Rather than `bash -c` you'll have a *much* easier time if you write a program which takes paths either as parameters or on standard input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that only way is to write the `variable` into a file and then capture it from the main shell. Here is how I handle it:

```
capture="capture.log"
text_to_capture="file_with_an_issue: "
[ -e ${capture} ] && rm ${capture}     #(1)
printf "%s\n" ${list_of_file_names[@]} | xargs -n1 -P4 -I {file} bash -c '
    # Process the file ...
    exit_status=$?
    [ ${exit_status} -ne 0 ] && echo "${text_to_capture}{file}" >> ${capture}'     #(2)

files_with_issues=$(grep -oP "(?<=${text_to_capture}).*" ${capture})     #(3)
```

**Some notes:**

1) `[ -e ${capture} ] && rm ${capture}`

Ensure the file is not existed, before appending any text.

2) `echo "${text_to_capture}{file}" >> ${capture}`

Append certain `text` and `variable` to the file by `>>` and list up all.

3) `grep -oP "(?<=text_to_capture).*" ${capture}`

Capture the `variable` from the file by the help of `grep` and `regex`

Answer (score 1):

## Answer to new question

If you need to do complex things with each file you'll want to pass it either as standard input or parameters to a *script*. The script can then output NUL-separated filenames which you can then capture in an array:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' -u 9 file
do
    files_with_issues+=("$file")
done 9< <(./process_files.sh <<< "${list_of_file_names[@]}")
```

## Answer to original question

Since

```
$ echo foo | xargs -I {file} bash -c 'echo "Information about {file}"'
Information about foo
```

you can do

```
$ info="$(echo foo | xargs -I {file} bash -c 'echo "Information about {file}"')"
```

Comment: I need some processing in subshell, there will be several output during execution. Then I just want to get some certain variables to the current shell.